# pcl_ros(hydro) fails to compile on Mac OSX 10.8.5

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro, osx, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is what I get compiling Hydro on OSX 10.8.5 Particularly I get the following errors during pcl_ros compilation.

```
       /Users/artemlenskiy/ros/hydro/src/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/features/feature.cpp:50:10: fatal error: 'pcl/io/io.h' file not found
    #include <pcl/io/io.h>
...
```

The reason is IO is turned off in homebrew PCL, and therefore the headers are missing.
Does William of anyone else know how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85721/pcl_ros(hydro)-fails-to-compile-on-mac-osx-10.8.5/) by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 709 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, I fixed this a while back and forgot to push it! Thanks for the heads up!

https://github.com/ros/homebrew-hydro/commit/b0694465dd3b096f1e00661228d50df23a8f8dd8

You should be able to:

```
brew uninstall pcl
brew update
brew install pcl
```

To resolve the issue.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-01**:
Thanks William, it perfectly works!